# Select a column of matrix in r by looping

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
mvn.var=matrix(c(3,1,1,4,6,7,8,9),4,2,byrow=T)
```

And I try

```
for (i in 1:dim(mvn.var)[2]) {
    y[i]=mvn.var[,i]
}
```

Because I want to have vectors `y[i]` where `y[i]` is a vector that consists of the elements of the `i`-th column of the previous `mvn.var` matrix.

I get:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In y[i] = mvn.var[, i] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In y[i] = mvn.var[, i] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign to an element of the vector. Try this instead,

```
mvn.var=matrix(c(3,1,1,4,6,7,8,9),4,2,byrow=T)
y = matrix(data=NA,2,4,byrow=T)
for (i in 1:dim(mvn.var)[2]) {
    y[i,]=mvn.var[,i]
}
```

However you can achieve the same result by merely transposing your matrix, e.g., `t(mvn.var)`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to put a vector of length 4 into something of length 1 (=i'th element of y). The message warns you, because y[i] will only contain the first element of the column.

Try making y a list:

```
mvn.var=matrix(c(3,1,1,4,6,7,8,9),4,2,byrow=T)
y <- list()
for (i in 1:dim(mvn.var)[2])
  y[[i]]=mvn.var[,i]
y

# [[1]]
# [1] 3 1 6 8
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 4 7 9
```